# JQuery form submit to an aspx -- form collection empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, forms

I have the following code in my HTML file (this is oversimplfied to save space and time):

```
<form role="form" name="popupForm" id="popupForm">
   <input type="hidden" name="season1" id="season1" value="fall" />
   <input type="hidden" name="season2" id="season2" value="fall" />
   <input type="hidden" name="season3" id="season3" value="fall" />
   <input type="hidden" name="ITEMCOUNT" id="ITEMCOUNT" value="3" />
</form>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="orderSave">Save Changes</button>
```

I then have a JQuery routine that IS getting called:

```
$("#orderSave").click(function () {

    $.post("ProductPopupLightboxSave.aspx", $('form#popupForm').serialize(), function (data) {


        $("#productModal").modal("hide");

    });
});
```

In the file ProductPopupLightboxSave.aspx I have the following code:

```
If IsNumeric(Request("ITEMCOUNT")) Then intItemCount = CInt(Request("ITEMCOUNT"))
```

The value in intItemCount is used in a For...Next loop to interate through the and grab the individual elements "season1", "season2", and "season3" (obviously the numbers vary depending upon the product) and saves the info to the database. The problem is that Request("ITEMCOUNT") is nothing when it gets here. In fact, it doesn't seem to serialize my form data at all.

**UPDATE:** *I have used the name element and that didn't fix anything. What I have noticed is that this is a .NET application and it has a RADSCRIPTMANAGER tag in the master page. It has an open form tag but not a closing one (it was done by another developer so I don't know the reason for that). It appears that this is getting in the way because I just changed the FORM tag to be a DIV tag with the exact same ID and with that change only the form data serializes.*

What am I doing wrong? I have even done an alert on the value of the #ITEMCOUNT and it is always correct. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you checked what is going on with success function? Might be you're getting an error and it's not trapped.

Comment: Well, you could have another issue. I tried an ajax code and it works with your code. Let me post it changing my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested in my computer using your form and it worked, however I had a strange behavior in IE 10. So I changed my code and it worked, find it below, using .ajax not .post

```
<form role="form" id="popupForm">
<input type="hidden" id="season1" name="season1" value="fall" />
<input type="hidden" id="season2" name="season2" value="fall" />
<input type="hidden" id="season3" name="season3" value="fall" />
<input type="hidden" id="ITEMCOUNT" name="ITEMCOUNT" value="3" />
</form>
```

Changed the button just in case, it worked with the other button too.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Button1"> More Save</button>
```

And set an .ajax post

```
$("#Button1").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Default.aspx',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('form#popupForm').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

For testing purposes I've added alerts on success and error, I'm posting to a default.aspx webpage and I get results properly.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Please note my update to this item. Changing the FORM tag to a DIV tag fixed the problem, but I don't understand why.

Comment: I believe it is something about the RADSCRIPTMANAGER tag to be honest. Thanks for taking the time to create a sample. I can see that it works.

Comment: This is the main issue always with asp.net, there're many scripts you don't control and it's not always easy to make jQuery works properly. You're welcome, I've been there more than once and I appreciate how helpful is this site :)